# One Access form to multiple Tables

Tags: forms, ms-access-2013

I am working on a form that connects to two separate tables. One table is a major database that holds every kind of expense that my department consists of while the other table consist of solely travel expenses. Neither of these tables have primary or foreign keys as some transactions can have duplicates as desperate charges or charges have the same dates.

I want to create one form (not including a subform) that adds new information to both of these tables with one form input.

> Basically a user will input and Account # on a form that will input new information for both the Account # field in the mass table as well as the Account # in the travel expense table.

Comment: They aren't erasing an old Account #. When an expense report comes in the user will input the information onto a new form which will then update each table with a new line. I just want to find out if it's possible to link that input control to add new information into two different tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update multiple tables in one statement, however, you can use a transaction to make sure that two UPDATE statements are treated atomically. You can also batch them to avoid a round trip.
lets say an example
//for table 1
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;

similarly for table 2
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;

Comment: So you're saying in the control source I'll write an update statement that says which row and column field to update?